# Extract 3 first numbers from 6 numbers from character string

Tags: r

I have some issues while working with text stings in R.

I have some string vector which consists of, combined, characters and numbers:

```
> a <- c("China ltd 123100","Morocco125312 Ytd")
> a

[1] "China ltd 123100"  "Morocco125312 Ytd"
```

The thing is that every element of `a` contains a sequence of 6 numbers and I need to extract first 3 numbers of every sequence.

Output should be:

```
[1] "123"  "125"
```

I need to do this with basic R functions since I am not able to install packages. Can you please help me, have no ideas how to do this.

Comment: Since you can't use packages adding this as a comment `stringr::str_extract(a, '\\d{3}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help:

```
substring(text = as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+", "", a, perl=TRUE)),first = 1,last = 3)

[1] "123" "125"
```

Comment: This way of extracting the numbers is a bit long-winded, but it isn't so bad that it is deserving of downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `gsub` like below

```
> gsub("\\D+(\\d{3}).*","\\1",a)
[1] "123" "125"
```